# Automate file decryption using gpg2

Tags: c#, gnupg

I am trying to automate a daily file decryption process using gpg2. My command line string is:

```
string strCommandLine = String.Format("echo {0}|gpg2.exe --passphrase-fd 0 -o \"{1}\" --decrypt \"{2}\"", p_passphrase, outputFilepath, p_encryptedFilepath);
```

It does output the decrypted file, but a box keeps popping up asking for the passphrase to be entered manually. I understand from reading around the internet that there is an issue with passphrases and gpg2 in the way I have done this above, but I don't how to resolve it. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- I have no experience with GnuPG in Windows, but assuming it's the same, adding **`--batch`** will probably take care of it.
- In Linux, adding **`--no-tty`** is always a good idea to deal with fringe cases (might apply to Windows as well) and **`--yes`** is required if you end up needing to overwrite files.
- Lastly, **`--trust-model always`** can come in handy in some cases. (Make sure to look that up before deciding to use it.)

Comment: Thanks, but I've decided that in the interest of security, it is probably best that the passphrase is entered manually and the decryption is automated.